# iOS: the background color of the header of my TableView is not changing anymore in iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios13, uibackgroundcolor

My TableView's header is not displaying well in iOS13. No matter what color I put, it always displays a light gray now...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{   //Section color & style

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *v = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;

    v.backgroundView.alpha = 1;
    v.textLabel.textColor = sectionColor;
    v.textLabel.font = sectionFont;
    v.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    v.textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
    v.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    v.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

iOS12:
[image: iOS12]

iOS13:
[image: iOS13]

It is strange because when I put a stop in the debugger in step by step, it displays me the good image in iOS13, but not in the app:

[image: stepbystep]
Any suggestions, thanks in advance ?

Comment: It's probably something related to adaptations for dark mode would be my guess.  Could you try using `v.contentView.backgroundColor = ...` ?

Comment: @R4N that's it, thank you :D You can put it in answer, I would validate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me.

```
v.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
```

instead of

```
v.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Answer (score 10):

I was noticing the same thing in one of my apps. 
Then saw a log message in the console:

> Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been
>   deprecated. Please set a custom UIView with your desired background
>   color to the backgroundView property instead.

Setting a custom `UIView` with the desired background color as the `backgroundView` of the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` solved the problem.

**Code sample**

```
class SomeHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func configure() {
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and show some code?  A generic view and setting it's background color in `willDisplayHeaderView` is not working for me

Comment: @GarySabo I've added a code sample to my answer. It configures the background view in a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass instead of the `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you but then where would SomeHeaderView be instantiated and used? 

Comment: never mind, I implemented this using `viewForHeaderInSection` and works well 

Answer (score 0):

Try to add overlay view and change this color for this view.

```
UIView *coloredView = [[UIView alloc] init];
coloredView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[v addSubview:coloredView];

[[coloredView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v.leadingAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
[[coloredView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v.trailingAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
[[coloredView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v.topAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
[[coloredView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:v.bottomAnchor constant:0] setActive:YES];
```